# what would be the official date of Magento 1 sunset?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, upgrade

Now we are in progress of Magento 2 upgrade. Some sources I read that early 2018 Magento 1 support will be closed.
If we get the Magento 1 official close date, we can decide our due date of upgrade.

Anybody having idea over here?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

***Superseding the superseding edit:*** [June 2020 is the official EOL as of 2018.](https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/supporting-magento-1-through-june-2020)

---

*Superseding edit:* [As was recently announced on Twitter by my CEO at Magento](https://twitter.com/mklave1/status/869735713155104768), this answer to this question is currently (6 June 2017) pending further announcements.*

Magento 1.x end of life is November 2018.

***Edit:*** [Tweet from our Head of Product](https://twitter.com/productpaul/status/830884917877682176): "November 18th 2018 to be exact."

Comment: Can a reference from an official source be provided?

Comment: You can email me at ben@magento.com and I'll tell you the same thing :-)

Comment: lol Ben! @kevin benmarks is with Magento, as an evangelist. This is would be straight beamed down from the mother ship. 

Comment: There's a good reason for this date: the Magento Enterprise Edition Agreement says that Magento will support the two previous versions for 3 years after a new version is made generally available. Magento 2.0's GA date was November 17, 2015 - making November 18, 2018 the first day without support for Magento 1.x. Edit: [more details](http://bit.ly/mage1eol)

Comment: When Magento 1 Team will do a complete statement what means End Of Life. Are they planning to support security patches for x years? For example wanncry pushed Microsoft creating patches for Windows XP. Will Magento Connect be closed? Bug Tracker for Magento 1 will be closed?

Comment: @benmarks Seems your answer here is incorrect? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/227879/3029

Comment: It was correct when offered. Is now outdated. Our SVP of tech posted the official EOL policy in May 2017: https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/ongoing-magento-1-support

Comment: @benmarks Could you edit and update your answer to the official EOL policy which is clearer to other users who find this topic? The lack of clarity on the web is mis-leading people that they have to fork out cash to upgrade which is not true, we have 18 months from the time that Magento officially announce the end of support and I would expect that through the blog or newsletter security updates for people subscribed.

Answer (score 5):

According to this post we can officially say bye bye to `Magento 1.x` in `June 2020` straight after T-20 cricket world-cup.

https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/supporting-magento-1-through-june-2020

Comment: Due to corona virus I don't think T-20 worldcup would happens :(

Answer (score 2):

Magento 1 is a great piece of software, the best shopping cart I ever used starting my experience long time ago with osCommerce. Those who consider it old they did not evaluate the treasure consisting of articles, true solutions, tons of free and paid extensions, themes, tutorials, books and many more. In any moment I can find something related to my issues for Magento 1.

What Magento 2 is actually offering? I hear a lot of people wanting to upgrade but did they evaluate the opportunities? A completely different platform adapted to "our days", a few expensive extensions, lack of support, a longer period of accommodating, missing books and tutorials. The only great thing I appreciate is the bug reporting system in Git. It will take around 3 - 4 years to get a complete competitive and powerful switch catching what Magento 1 offers right now.

Today Magento 1 is like a person around age of 40, mature. Everything you want from it there is on the market.  Abandoning Magento 1 is a bad idea even for security patches, but if you look deeper they abandoned it long time ago about 2 years ago. Just see how slow the team reacts to bugs reported in their system. Only the community keeps it alive because it's still the best shopping cart on the market.

Answer (score 2):

Support for **1.x** will be till **June 2020**

No need to worry about Magento 1 End-of-life in 2018. Sure, it might be the time to start planning migrations to Magento 2 but it is not that you will be left with an unsupported platform this year if you don’t.