# From where can i download Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, version, download

Is there a official website for downloading Magento 1.9 ?

Is that version still supported by Magento or is there a support community for this version available?

Comment: If you have written the same thing in google you could have got your answer.

Comment: I also want to know answer to this.

Answer (score 2):

All Magento version are available on Magento Official website.

Go to : https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

After login click on "Release Archive" Tab, You will get all available version of magento.

Comment: I'm not seeing Magento 1 download here, perhaps it is no longer available here?

Answer (score 0):

you can download here :

https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

you can check below link for support

[what would be the official date of Magento 1 sunset?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159422/what-would-be-the-official-date-of-magento-1-sunset/159424#159424)