# Magento 1 end of life on Nov. 2018 or not?

Tags: magento-1, upgrade, security

Please see [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/159424/3029) by an internal staff of Magento who states that:

> Magento 1.x end of life is November 2018.

However on their official blog, [this post](https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/ongoing-magento-1-support) states:

> Magento 1 has been and will continue to be supported for the
>   foreseeable future.
>
> ...
>
> Lastly, we are committing to a minimum 18-month notice before we make
>   any changes to our support levels.

I'm now confused. Ben says end of life is Nov. 2018 but I haven't received any 18-month notice of support level changes as of now, so according to the official news, it shouldn't be end of life in Nov. 2018 yet.

We have invested much in the themes and extensions of our Magento 1 store.

Magento 2 is awesome but since everything's working great, we hate to do everything (design, functions, user exp, tests, optimizations, etc.) over again as stuff are completely incompatible between the two versions.

The only concern is security.

So is Magento 1 going end of life and not supported beyond Nov. 2018 or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can check that Ben posted his answer on **February 12, 2017**, while the official Magento blog post was posted on **May 30, 2017**.

So **you can trust on the official Magento blog post.**

And since there is no such official announcement (18 months notice) yet for stopping the support for Magento 1.x, we can still use Magento 1.x for our current installations.

Comment: Then why didn't he update the answer. He should be more than aware about this. The answer is misleading lots of readers.

Comment: @datasn.io, don't you trust on official blog post of Magento?

Comment: @datasn.io, don't you trust on official blog post of Magento?

Comment: I do but the official post was also almost 1 year old and I see no collateral information about that on the official site anywhere else and no comments on the post. It just doesn't feel as official.

Comment: You can post your concern at https://magento.com/contact-us

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1 is end-of-life as of July 1, 2020.

Official announcements from Magento:

- Blog post from September 6, 2018: [Supporting Magento 1 through June 2020](https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/supporting-magento-1-through-june-2020)
- Blog post from June 24, 2020: [Support for Magento 1 Software Ends June 30, 2020](https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/support-magento-1-software-ends-june-30-2020)